# how to parsing data json from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

i want to parsing json from javascript to php
this my javascript code

```
var Dataconvert;
            var asetid = new Array();
            $("#simpanmodifikasi").click(function(){
                var table = $('#tableasal tbody');
                table.find('tr').each(function (row, input) {
                    // var coba = $(this).find('input'),
                    // asetid = coba.eq(0).val();
                    asetid[row] = {
                        "asetid" : $(this).find('input:eq(0)').val(),
                        "namabarang" : $(this).find('input:eq(1)').val(),
                    }
                    Dataconvert = $.toJSON(asetid);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo site_url('fixed/modification/tes');?>",
                        type:"POST",
                        data:Dataconvert,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        cache : false,
                        success:function(html){
                           alert(html);
                         }
                    })                        
                });                   
            })
```

how to parsing this json in php ???, i am new in javascript and json,
i appreciate your help

Comment: In PHP service, use `json_decode()`

Comment: like this json_decode(Dataconvert) ???

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['data'])`

Comment: @Tushar i try to print_r this but nothing happens, can you help me, i see the error "data is not defined"

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve including the PHP code, the inputs you use, the expected outputs and any errors you may get. As is, I don't even understand your question, much less where you have problems.

Comment: I do not know what to do,

Comment: I want to parse json in php by sending json with jquery but I'm wondering how to retrieve data from earlier javascript in php, I have to use what syntax to do the parsing
and sorry if my english is not good I'm learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you need to change `$.toJSON(asetid)` to `JSON.stringify(asetid)`.
But, if, somehow you still want to use `$.toJSON(asetid)`, you need to include the `jquery-json` plugin from http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ on your page.

**Second**, I think the ajax request part should be put outside of the iterator function, otherwise, you will be making an ajax request for each row of the table.
Here is the revised code:

```js
var Dataconvert;
var asetid = new Array();
$("#simpanmodifikasi").click(function(){
    var table = $('#tableasal tbody');
    table.find('tr').each(function (row, input) {
        // var coba = $(this).find('input'),
        // asetid = coba.eq(0).val();
        asetid[row] = {
            "asetid" : $(this).find('input:eq(0)').val(),
            "namabarang" : $(this).find('input:eq(1)').val(),
        }
    });
  
    //these should be outside the 'each' iterator
    Dataconvert = JSON.stringify(asetid);
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo site_url('fixed/modification/tes');?>",
        type:"POST",
        data:Dataconvert,
        dataType : 'json',
        cache : false,
        success:function(html){
           alert(html);
         }
    })
})
```

**Third**, now the answer to your question.
The ajax request will send the stringified JSON in the POST body.
Example:

```
[{"asetid":"10","namabarang":"Buku"},{"asetid":"30","namabarang":"Laptop"}]
```

To read it from the PHP side (the `fixed/modification/tes` script), you can manually read it from the standard input and parse it using `json_decode`.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
?>
```

which will result in something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [asetid] => 10
            [namabarang] => Buku
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [asetid] => 30
            [namabarang] => Laptop
        )

)
```

Comment: not on the console log, if you really have that PHP script, you will be able to see it on your browser's network log. I assume you will want to process the $data further in PHP, so that is for illustration only to give you an idea what the data looks like in php.

Comment: BTW, if you want to return a message back to the JS to be alerted, you can replace `print_r($data);` with something like `echo json_encode(sizeof($data) . ' data received');`. Basically, it should be a valid JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input');
```

`json_decode` takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

and now you can access the variables like this.

```
$firstVariable = $data -> var1;
$secondVariable = $data -> var2;
.....
.....
.....
```