# Having trouble retrieving JSON with curl to parse in php

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm attempting too fetch and parse JSON in PHP via curl. I am unable to parse the response, and see it dumping to my screen instead. Here is sample code.

```
<?php

$url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'X-Mashape-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL); ## this seems to be the line printing the response?

curl_close($cURL);

echo "<br />--------------------------------------------------------<br />";

var_dump($cURL);

echo "<br />--------------------------------------------------------<br />";

var_dump($result);

echo "<br />--------------------------------------------------------<br />";

$json = json_decode($result);

echo "<br />--------------------------------------------------------<br />";

print_r($json);

echo "<br />--------------------------------------------------------<br />";

echo $json->word;
echo $json->definitions[0]->definition;

echo "<br />--------------------------------------------------------<br />";

?>
```

And the output is:

```
{"word":"incredible","definitions":[{"definition":"beyond belief or understanding","partOfSpeech":"adjective"}]}
--------------------------------------------------------
resource(2) of type (Unknown) 
--------------------------------------------------------
bool(true) 
--------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------
1
--------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------
```

See how my JSON is appearing on screen before my first echo statement? Why is this happening?

Comment: how about using `json_decode` ? and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253131/how-to-parsing-data-json-from-javascript-to-php . Can you show us the javascript code? (* and you have a 1 at the end of your response)

Comment: I am using json_decode. And I dont know where that '1' comes from!

Comment: when I wrote the comment you didn't use the `json_decode`, can we see also the javascript code that generates the response?

Comment: Full php code added, along with new attempts and full output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cURL doesn't return transfer but it outputs. You must not output your transfer. Add CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option with true value. Also in the response JSON, definitions is not an object it's array and it will be parsed as array in php too. Also there is no `attachments` key in response so you can't access it.

```
$url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'X-Mashape-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'Accept: application/json'
));

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // add this line to catch your response with curl_exec function. 

$result = curl_exec($cURL); 

$json = json_decode($result);

print_r($json); // this will print parsed json.

echo $json->word;
echo $json->definitions[0]->definition; // Get First Entry of definitions
```

Comment: This didnt work either. I have now added this example to my original post too.

Comment: Can you tell us what `var_dump($result);` generates ? Don't delete anything paste it as it's.

Comment: {"word":"incredible","definitions":[{"definition":"beyond belief or understanding","partOfSpeech":"adjective"}]}bool(true) 1

Comment: Can you also run that code and tell us what it generates ? Code : `$result = curl_exec($cURL);
$json = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($json);`

Comment: Now added some more options and edited my question to show more clearly what each echo outputs.

Comment: but still you didn't use `json_decode` with the second parameter `true`

Comment: I have tried with second parameter true and without - it makes no difference to what gets printed.

Comment: Edited my comment check it.

Comment: Great! Setting "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" has fixed it now. Thanks!

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. The actual problem has nothing to do with JSON parsing, it's about why CURL is echoing instead of returning. The OP even noted this, yet still phrased the questions as if JSON parsing was the issue. If you clearly reason through your problems and communicate them accurately, you'll find more when Ggoogling the web and searching SO, and will get yourself faster answers to your questions when you do ask them on SO.

Comment: @JAAulde This is clear in hindsight, after the question has an answer, but when I asked the question, it looked to me like a parsing problem. I didnt know it wasnt until this answer was given.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$json = json_decode($json);` and then u can use `$json['word']` and so on.

Comment: I already had this before the code examples I listed. It didnt work. Have updated my code snippet now.